# PHP problems parsing a bible book string

Tags: php, string, parsing, variables, explode

I hope you can help me.

I have a string like the following

Luke 1:26-38

And I would like to be able to break it up into tokens or individual variables so that I can use the variables in an SQL query.

I've tried using explode, however I've only been able to make it explode on one character such as : or -

My string has : and - and also a space between the name and the first number.

My goal is to have:

```
    $name = Luke;
    $book = 1;
    $from = 26;  
    $to = 38;
```

Is anyone able to help please.

Many thanks

Comment: How did you used `explode()` so it didn't worked ?

Comment: So far explode(":", $data); where the string is in the variable $data

Comment: and also list($book, $chapter) = explode(":", $data);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list( $name, $book, $from, $to ) = preg_split( '/[ :-]/', 'Luke 1:26-38' );

echo $name; //"Luke"

    /* Split results in an Array
(
    [0] => Luke
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 26
    [3] => 38
)
     */
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with a simple string scanning ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZC6bBF)):

```
$r = sscanf("Luke 1:26-38", "%s %d:%d-%d", $name, $book, $from, $to);
```

The varibales then contain the information. `%s` represents a string (without spaces), `%d` a decimal. See [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf).

---

To make this "bible safe", it needs some additional modifications:

```
$r = sscanf($string, "%[ a-zA-Z] %d:%d-%d", $name, $book, $from, $to);
$name = trim($name);
```

([Second demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/m5B3V5)).

Comment: I like this one better, was thinking too much in terms of what I would do in javascript

Comment: You will need to make amends to this code  in order to support the numbered books of the bible (i.e. I Timothy, II Timothy, etc).

Comment: @worsnupd: Right, but which is the name of that roman numeral in front for the variable?

Comment: It's part of the name of the book. It should end up inside the `$name` variable as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "Luke 1:26-38";
preg_match('#^(\w+)\s(\d+):(\d+)-(\d+)$#', $string, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

regex is hard to configure for this because of the multiple configurations of bible book names, chapter and verse num. Because some books begin with a number and some books have multiple spaces in the book names.

I came up with this for building a sql query, it works for these passage search types..
(John), (John 3), (Joh 3:16), (1 Thes 1:1)

Book names can be 3 letter abbreviations.

Does unlimited individual word search and exact phrase.

```
$string = $_GET['sstring'];
$type = $_GET['stype'];
switch ($type){ 
    case "passage":
        $book = "";
        $chap = "";
        $stringarray = explode(':', $string); // Split string at verse refrence/s, if exist.
        $vref = $stringarray[1]; 
        $vrefsplit = explode('-', $vref);// Split verse refrence range, if exist.
        $minv = $vrefsplit[0];
        $maxv = $vrefsplit[1]; // Assign min/max verses.
        $bc = explode(" ", $stringarray[0]); // Split book string into array with space as delimiter.
        if(is_numeric($bc[count($bc)-1])){ // If last book array element is numeric?
            $chap = array_pop($bc); // Remove it from array and assign it to chapter.
            $book = implode(" ", $bc); // Put remaining elemts back into string and assign to book.
        }else{
            $book = implode(" ", $bc); // Else book array is just book, convert back to string.
        }
        // Build the sql query.
        $query_rs1 = "SELECT * FROM kjvbible WHERE bookname LIKE '$book%'";
        if($chap != ""){
            $query_rs1.= " AND chapternum='$chap'";
        }
        if($maxv != ""){
            $query_rs1.= " AND versenum BETWEEN '$minv' AND '$maxv'";
        }else if($minv != ""){
            $query_rs1.= " AND versenum='$minv'";
        }
    break;
    case "words":
        $stringarray = explode(" ", $string); // Split string into array.<br />
        // Build the sql query.
        $query_rs1 = "SELECT * FROM kjvbible WHERE versetext REGEXP '[[:<:]]". $stringarray[0] ."[[:>:]]'";
        if(count($stringarray)>1){
            for($i=1;$i<count($stringarray);$i++){
                $query_rs1.= " AND versetext REGEXP '[[:<:]]". $stringarray[$i] ."[[:>:]]'";
            }
        }
    break;
    case "xphrase":
        // Build the sql query.
        $query_rs1 = "SELECT * FROM kjvbible WHERE versetext REGEXP '[[:<:]]". $string ."[[:>:]]'";
    break;
    default :
    break;
}
```